# Can't deploy the kubeflow pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube, kubeflow, mlops

I am following this tutorial https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/installation/localcluster-deployment/. Before that I succcessfully started minikube (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/).
When I run this command:

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
```

I get the following error:

```
error: hit 27s timeout running 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --depth=1 origin HEAD'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, needed to update (in my case reinstall) git